# Index a sequence Python

Tags: python, sequence

I have this code. I am new in programming. Sorry if this is a silly question.

```
import random
N = int(input("Number of sequences to generate: \n"))
def randseq(abc, length):
    return "".join([random.choice(abc) for i in range(random.randint(1, length))])
for i in range(N):
    print(randseq("ATCG", 120))
```

I got this output:

TGCGTGCACATGATTGACAGGGTCCGTCCGCAACC

TACCGTCATACGCTGAATTGGTCGCATGCCAAAGTACACGTGTTATA

GAAACGTCCGCGATGATTAAGACCACAA

How can I get an output like this:

Sequence 1:

TGCGTGCACATGATTGACAGGGTCCGTCCGCAACC

Sequence 2:

TACCGTCATACGCTGAATTGGTCGCATGCCAAAGTACACGTGTTATA

.
.

Sequence N:

....

Comment: If the missing `Sequence x` is the problem, add `print(f'Sequence {i}:')` to your `for` loop before printing the actual sequence.

Comment: @marcelh you should post that as an answer, that does seem to be what he's looking for

Comment: @marcelh that's exactly what I was looking for... It works!

Comment: @Schalton: You are absolutely right, I was in a hurry for work. Nevertheless, it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the desired output to your existing `for` loop in the same way you print your sequences while re-using your loop variable `i`. To start with `Sequence 1:` , instead of `Sequence 0:` you can add `i + 1` to the `print` statement.

```py
for i in range(N):
    print(f'Sequence {i + 1}:')
    print(randseq("ATCG", 120))
```

More information regarding `print` can be found [here](https://realpython.com/python-print/). More information to format strings can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting).